# Google Plus Profile Picture Google Play Game Services

Tags: eclipse, google-plus, google-play-games

I've already seen all post in this forum but i haven't found anything.
How can i show in an ImageView the Profile picture of google plus of person who log in my app? with ImageManager?
can you show some code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method below does what you want.

```
public class AvatarImage extends ImageView  {
    Bitmap image;
    public static final String TAG = "AvatarImage";

    public AvatarImage(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar);
    }

    /**
     * This method takes the participant object and attempts to 
     * download avatar of the participant from google plus
     * if this is unsuccesful default avatar is shown
     * @param p
     */
    public void setImageFromParticipant(Participant p) {
        ImageManager im = ImageManager.create(getContext());    
        im.loadImage(this, p.getIconImageUri(), R.drawable.avatar);
        try{
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)this.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. That is pretty straightforward and works for me. If you have problems integrating it to your code you should be more specific how it doesn't work. So that I can help.

Comment: ImageHelper is my own class. The above is not copy paste code; you should omit that line I am editing the answer

Comment: this is the logcat that show when i run my app:                    09-08 17:20:47.560: E/AndroidRuntime(27415): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-08 17:20:47.560: E/AndroidRuntime(27415): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageBroadcastReceiver: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageManager$c

Comment: and this is the code:                                       AvatarImage ai = new AvatarImage(this);  ai.setImageFromParticipant(getGamesClient().getCurrentPlayer().getIconImageUri());
profile_person.addView(ai);                                                                profile_person is a relativeLayout and I changed setImageFromParticipant function with an uri on the brackets

Comment: This is a known bug you have to wait for the next update.Here is the details https://code.google.com/p/play-games-platform/issues/detail?id=7

Comment: There is an old version of play game services that works. I use it for now. Next version should be free of this bug as well. You can upvote the bug.

Answer (score 0):

The code as shown for the other answer from John is correct, however, there is currently an issue with Google Play Service Library as shown here [Google Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/play-games-platform/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Platform%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=7) for anyone using ver 10 of the library (and perhaps ver 9.. version 8 is good).  Unfortunately for this issue, if you even attempt to get the URI decoded by ImageManager, Google Play Services quits working.   Either wait for next ver of the library, or try to get ahold of ver 8.
 (I couldn't put this in as a comment on the answer above, so had to go with a new answer...)

Comment: i see it and i did to know you what happen :)